# How do I calculate the minimum and maximum amount of nodes and leaves in a rooted tree?

Tags: graph, tree, computer-science, directed-graph

I'm looking to calculate the minimum and maximum amount of nodes and leaves in a rooted tree with the height h and the degree d.

I'm guessing the minimum amount of leaves is always 1 (if h >= 2).
The maximum amount of nodes should be G^(h-2), the leaves should be G^(h-1). 
For the minimum amount of nodes I'm clueless.

Am I correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the tree has height h and degree d the following applies.

**Minimum numbers of nodes**

To construct a tree of height h with as few nodes as possible, you'll want that each node only has one child. Consequently you'll need h nodes.

**Maximum numbers of nodes**

To use as many nodes as possible you'll want that every node (except the leafs) has as many childern as possible, i.e. d childern. This will look like:

```
level      nodes at level 

  1              1    (d^0)
  2              d    (d^1)
  3              d^2
  4              d^3
```

So the number of nodes is a sum like

```
num_nodes = d^0 + d^1 + d^2 + d^3 + ....
```

This is a geometric sum that can be calculated as:

```
num_nodes = (1 - d^h)/(1 - d)
```